# Give access to an image for a limited time until an admin removes the access right?

Tags: php, security, scalability, download

I want people to have access to images for a limited amount of time.
Example they pay for x.jpg and they have access to it until I decide they
no more have access to download it.

note: The 'images' server that store x.jpg is independant from the 'www' server so the system
can scale easily. (The two servers don't share data, db access or so...)

The best solution I found so far is this one:

On the www server, I generate an encrypted string that contains two parameters:
"filename" and "expiration_stmp". I pass this encrypted string to a script on the image server
that decrypts it, check if the expiration stmp is not in the past and if everything is ok, 
read the file on disk, output the correct headers and output the image binary data to the client.

So I have a link like this one on www server: "img src=http://IMAGES.myserver.com/get.php?XJDKUJHKDJSHJKDHJKHJKDJKDJKD"
where the "XJDKUJHKDJSHJKDHJKHJKDJKDJKD" when decrypted will extract to filename=x.jpg,expiration_stmp=132920302030
and get.php on images server will contains something like header('Content-type...bblablabl'); readfile(x.jpg).....

The problem I have to solve is the fact that at the time I generate the encrypted string XJDKUJHKDJSHJKDHJKHJKDJKDJKD, 
I cannot know the expiration_stmp because the access right can be removed by an admin anytime by in the future, from 1 minute to 5 days.
So when an admin in the admin panel remove the right to read the file for that particular user, the user must be denied access
to the file.

To handle that, I thought of regenerating the page that contains the links every hour by a forced refresh of the page to generate new encrypted string that contains new expiration_stmps that are valid for 1 hour maximum. So the links "img src=http://images.myserver.com/get.php?XJDKUJHKDJSHJKDHJKHJKDJKDJKD" would be valid only for 1 hour,  So when an admin cancels the access right of a user, I just refuse to regenerate a new encrypted string so the user can no more access the file after the last generated expiration_stmp has expired (1 hour max).

For now it is the best solution I found....I would love to hear any thoughts or better way to handle such a situation?

thanks

Comment: What's to stop people from just saving the image to their hard drive?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible without a database.  I also disagree with your statement that using a database makes this unable to scale.  If the admin wants to revoke the permission, he must alter some piece of data somewhere, and if it's not a db row, what is there to change?

Comment: sure they can save the image but many people will not save the images if they think they can have access to it later on.....so when they discover they are denied access to the image page, if they try to access the images through the links they will be unable to do so

Comment: i guess google cant scale as it uses sessions and a db, sarcasm aside, you need to store user credentials and access times all suitable for a db.

Comment: What I (try) to explain is that the images server and www server do not share 'user credentials'. The two servers would share only the key to encrypt/decrypt the encrypted string that is passed from one to the other

Comment: sounds like the 'base' set up of your servers is borked; from the little of question that makes much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you under the impression that restricting by user or session won't scale. You could probably generate an access code instead of your encrypred string. Stor the access code in the DB linked to the image you are supposed to serve, as well as th user id. If the admin wants to remove access just delete the record, or flag it as expired. Databases are very quick and there is no reason a database with proper indexes shouldn't be able to handle this, even of scaled up to millions of active images.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be using a database in the following structor :

- Create a database with 2 tables (you could add more if you need) token, image.

token : token will have a field for userID which will point to another table to store user's info , an image ID which will refer to an image in the image database, and an expiry date and an ID.

image : it will have ID, imagename

for the download link, you could simply do : download.php?tokenID=xxx  and the script would go and check if the expiry date is in the past or not, this will happen in real time when the user clicks on the file so you wont have the problem of unauthorized access. once the expiry is checked you can get the imageID from the token field and find the image on the other server.

You can easily scale this structure by having one or more database servers (one should be enough in my opinion) and connect all the file/script servers to the remote database server.

without having a database it would be impossible considering that the file will only get the date from the GET vars and cant check it with any reference, and the system should be easily hackable if you use any common php functions to encrypt the vars.